# Back button no longer appears after reload

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using 1.3.0 RC1 the back button is never shown on any page after a page reload of a "#subpage".

I understand that the back button should not be there on the first page when you reload a "#page2" page. But if you click on another link to navigate to an other page you should get the back button but it isn't.

Repro steps:
- load site to page 1
- go on page 2 and notice the back button
- reload the page (which is at "#page2")
- page 2 load without the back button (correct)
- go to page 3 and notice the back button is NOT shown

At this point I expect to see a back button. Even if I go further pages 4, 5, 6... it NEVER shows a back button.

I have added the attribute `data-add-back-btn="true"` to pseudo pages containers. I also have added `$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;` on `mobileinit` event on the `document` object. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

This must work, I have tested it on jQm 1.2 and 1.3 RC1, here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="second" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header"> 
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#third" class="ui-btn-right">Back</a>          
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="third" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header"> 
            <h3>
                Third Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#fourth" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>  
    <div data-role="page" id="fourth" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Fourth Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

If you want, send me your example and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can be done for web sites like this:

your starting page id = "pageIndex"

if you are using jquerymobile1.2.0.js, then modify the framework code like this:

    if ( o.addBackBtn &&
                role === "header" &&
                ***$page.jqmData( "url" ) !== "pageIndex"***) {

                // framework code modified for back button id: sheetal 08/02/2013

                if (backBtnId !== undefined) {
                    backBtn = $( "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='ui-btn-left' data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"rel='back' data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"icon='arrow-l' id='" + backBtnId + "'>"+ o.backBtnText +"</a>" )
                        // If theme is provided, override default inheritance
                        .attr( "data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"theme", o.backBtnTheme || thisTheme )
                        .prependTo( $this );                    

                }else {

                    backBtn = $( "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='ui-btn-left' data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"rel='back' data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"icon='arrow-l'>"+ o.backBtnText +"</a>" )
                    // If theme is provided, override default inheritance
                    .attr( "data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"theme", o.backBtnTheme || thisTheme )
                    .prependTo( $this );

                }
            }
```